# my articles are lost after upgrading php version by server host

Tags: mysql, joomla, migration, server

I Have a joomla site in version 1.0.11 . My site is in French. When my server host upgrade php . My some articles missing ... May be some encoding issues i don't know. I Need help of any expert.

Articles are missing from backend but showing on frontend . Only those articles are missing which include ã, ã, ¢, â‚

I have change various steps from google but my issue isn’t resolved.

Comment: Please edit your question without capslock.

Comment: It sounds like they aren't lost, just not displaying.  Your host could let you stay on an old php, but this is really not recommended. Version 1.0 of Joomla has not been supported in many years and is not designed for modern versions of PHP an MySQL.  You really should try to migrate even though it will involve some headaches it will be worth it.